# In python, "export" a custom-tailored object from a module

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, import, export

In **JavaScript**, specifically in **node.js** setting, one can spell `module.exports = 13;` in `module.js`, then `x = import ("module.js");` elsewhere and have 13 assigned to *x* directly.

This saves some code when a module exports a single function, and I notice a lot of widely used packages (such as *through2*) make use of it.

Is there a way to do the same in **Python**? With some black magic, maybe?

I do have heard of a thing called *loader* that's, I guess, supposed to do some manipulations with a module before making it available. In particular, I think *SaltStack* makes use of something like that in `salt.loader`, but the code is too hard for me to follow. I imagine we could write a function similar to this:

```
def loader(module):
    m = __import__(module)
    return m["__exports__"]
```

— Then define `__exports__` somewhere in a module we want to import and enjoy functionality very similar to **JavaScript**'s `module.exports` mechanics. But unfortunately `TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` prevents us from doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Python has importing built in to the language at a more basic level than Javascript does, almost all use cases are covered by a simple [import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

For your example, all it really boils down to is:

```py
from module import exports as x
```

So, there's not need to look for code savings by changing `module`.

The other part of the question is how, as a module author, would you restrict people to seeing only a single symbol.

Generally this is not required except to help users know what are public functions vs implementation details. Python has a few common idioms for this:

- Any names that start with a leading underscore, such as `_helper`, are considered *private*. They can be accessed as normal, but the implication is you should not.
- If a module level variable `__all__ = [...]` exists, only the strings it contains are considered *public*. The names must seperatedly be declared in the module.

As well as being documentation, both of these do affect one aspect of the module import:

```py
from module import *
```

Using a star import is generally discouraged, but only *public names* will be brought in to the local namespace.

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking I understood that, while we can't say `m["__exports__"]` due to module object's class not having `__getitem__` method, we can still access some of the module's elements with *"dot"* notation: `m.__exports__` works.

Another way: screen all module level names off with an underscore and assign the object to be exported to a variable named after the module, then `from module import *`.

*loader.py:*

```
def loader(module):
    m = __import__(module)
    return m.__exports__
```

*exports.py:*

```
def _f():
    return 13

_a = 31

exports = {"p6": _f, "p8": _a}

__exports__ = exports
```

*Python 2.7:*

```
>>> import loader
>>> e = loader.load ("exports")
>>> e
{'p8': 31, 'p6': <function _f at 0x7fb79d494cf8>}
>>> from exports import *
>>> exports
{'p8': 31, 'p6': <function _f at 0x7fb79d494cf8>}
```

*Python 3:*

```
>>> import loader
>>> e = loader.load ("exports")
>>> e
{'p6': <function _f at 0x7f88ae229ae8>, 'p8': 31}
>>> from exports import *
>>> exports
{'p6': <function _f at 0x7f88ae229ae8>, 'p8': 31}
```

In the first way proposed, I unfortunately cannot use `__all__` in `loader.load` to filter only listed names from a module being loaded since `__getitem__` is not defined for module object.

In the second way proposed I don't get so much control (in that a malicious module can export arbitrary names and manipulate my namespace) and flexibility (in that I cannot assign the module's exported object to arbitrary name anywhere in my code).

So, there is still a bit left to be desired here.